# realm `! Cannot set computer password: Access denied`

Tags: active-directory, debian, ldap, ad-certificate-services

I'm trying to connect my debian machine to a windows server, and can't make it work.

As root, `kinit -V myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM` returns

```
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM
Password for myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM: 
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

`realm discover MYDOMAIN.COM` gives

```
mydomain.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: MYDOMAIN.COM
  domain-name: mydomain.com
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
```

I believe I have all the required packages installed, since `dpkg-query -l 'sssd-tools' 'sssd' 'adcli' 'samba-common-bin' 'libnss-sss' 'libpam-sss'` returns

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                Version                Architecture           Description
+++-===================================-======================-======================-===========================================================================
ii  adcli                               0.8.2-1+b1             amd64                  Tool for performing actions on an Active Directory domain
ii  libnss-sss:amd64                    1.15.0-3               amd64                  Nss library for the System Security Services Daemon
ii  libpam-sss:amd64                    1.15.0-3               amd64                  Pam module for the System Security Services Daemon
ii  samba-common-bin                    2:4.5.8+dfsg-2+deb9u1+ amd64                  Samba common files used by both the server and the client
ii  sssd                                1.15.0-3               amd64                  System Security Services Daemon -- metapackage
ii  sssd-tools                          1.15.0-3               amd64                  System Security Services Daemon -- tools
```

So everything seems fine, but I can't join the network.
`realm join --membership-software=adcli MYDOMAIN.COM -U myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM --verbose` gives

```
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.mydomain.com
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
 * Successfully discovered: mydomain.com
Password for myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM: 
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain mydomain.com --domain-realm MYDOMAIN.COM --domain-controller XXX.XX.XXX.XXX --login-type user --login-user myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM --stdin-password
 * Using domain name: mydomain.com
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: myLocalhost
 * Using domain realm: mydomain.com
 * Sending netlogon pings to domain controller: ldap://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
 * Received NetLogon info from: HI-ROOT03.mydomain.com
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-X6zN48/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-6SRoUP
 * Authenticated as user: myUserName@MYDOMAIN.COM
 * Looked up short domain name: MYSHORTDOMAIN
 * Using fully qualified name: myLocalhost.mydomain.com
 * Using domain name: mydomain.com
 * Using computer account name: myLocalhost
 * Using domain realm: mydomain.com
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: myLocalhost
 * Generated 120 character computer password
 * Using keytab: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
 * Found computer account for myLocalhost$ at: CN=myLocalhost,OU=Employee Computers,OU=Place1,OU=UserDevices,OU=Workstations,OU=ENTERPRISE,DC=mydomain,DC=com
 ! Cannot set computer password: Access denied
adcli: joining domain mydomain.com failed: Cannot set computer password: Access denied
 ! Insufficient permissions to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Insufficient permissions to join the domain
```

Comment: What do the logs on the domain controller say?

Comment: How do I access them?

Comment: Why the downvote? I believe my question is well-formulated, and reflects an error that other users might encounter. I believe that the links between Debian and active directory are not so well documented, and that such question could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot set computer password: Access denied

The error message seems pretty straightforward to me. The user you're attempting to join as doesn't appear to have permissions to reset the password on the existing "myLocalhost" computer account in that Employee Computers OU.

Should it? Is "myUserName" in the Domain Admins group? If not, has the user been granted other explicit permissions on computer accounts in that OU?  Standard user accounts in a well managed Active Directory typically can't just join computers willy nilly.

Comment: I probably don't understand the purpose of the `join` command of Active Directory, then. I have an account on the "myLocalhost" computer, I even have root access to it, but no, I'm not part of the Domain Admins groups. I want to connect to that server because I believe that, as long as I am not connected to that server, I can't use the ethernet connection or use the shared printer on my computer. This might be completely unrelated, as I said, I have a very poor understanding of what Active Directory is doing.

Comment: The typical reason one "joins" a computer to Active Directory is to enable logging in to the computer with an Active Directory account rather than a local account. I can't really speak to your network or printer issues.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning - I received this error attempting to join a domain and it was because there was already a Kerberos host principal for the linux box. Removing the key allowed me to join the domain successfully. Perhaps the permissions error is related to not being able to overwrite the existing principal.